# MySQL Function with LAST_INSERT_ID() giving unexpected results

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

I have spent 24 hours on this and need to leverage existing knowledge for speedsake.

I have this mysql function:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `db`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `insertindb`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `insertindb`(itemtype  VARCHAR(10), dname VARCHAR (50), id INTEGER, fname VARCHAR(50), lname VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS INT(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE ret INT;
    DECLARE ret2 INT;
    IF itemtype = 'state' THEN 
        INSERT IGNORE INTO state (`name`) VALUES (dname);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO ret;       
        IF ret = 0 THEN
           SELECT `id` INTO ret2 FROM state WHERE `name` LIKE dname;
           SET ret = ret2;
        END IF;              
    END IF;
  RETURN ret;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The objective? When a state already exists in the `state` table, it should return the id column (which is the auto-increment key). When it does not exist, it should insert it and return the newly (auto) assigned id.

The function is working but doing 2 things I do not want:

1) when the record already exists, it returns zero rather than the id of the existing record. My code is designed to address this but its not working Pls note I defined an index on the table to ensure state.name is unique in the table so that INSERT IGNORE works

2) the LAST_INSERT_ID() keeps incrementing even when the record exists and thus nothing was inserted. So for instance if the state table has only one record to start with (say id==>1, name ==> 'State A',) if I call the function 2 times to try re-inserting 'State A' (which will not insert as mentioned in point 1 above) and then call it again to insert 'State B', the table will now have a 2nd record id==>4,name ==> 'State B' skipping id values 2 and 3. Is there a way to have LAST_INSERT_ID work differently?

My code now

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE ret,ret2 INT;

IF itemtype = 'state' THEN 
    SELECT `id` INTO ret FROM state WHERE `name` LIKE dname;
    #insert into debug (dump1,dump2) values ('ret will be',ret);
    IF ret IS NULL OR ret = '' THEN

        INSERT IGNORE INTO state (`name`) VALUES (dname);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO ret2;  
        #SELECT `id` INTO ret FROM state WHERE `name` LIKE dname;
        RETURN ret2;
    ELSE
        RETURN ret;
    END IF; 
END IF;
```

END$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorenz already gave you the solution:

```
 SELECT `id` INTO ret FROM state WHERE `name` LIKE dname;
 IF ret IS NULL THEN
     INSERT IGNORE INTO state (`name`) VALUES (dname);
     SELECT `id` INTO ret FROM state WHERE `name` LIKE dname;
 END IF;
```

If you have multiple calls to the same function in the same time, there is a chance that you still get gap between ids, then you need different approach:

1) remove the auto_increment on your id
2) create an unique index on id
3) use this kind of query to insert new values:

```
INSERT INTO state (name, id)
SELECT dname, MAX(id) + 1 FROM state
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM state WHERE name=dname);
SELECT id INTO ret FROM state WHERE name=dname;
```

It may not work for the first state when MAX(id) returns NULL.

Comment: I'm going with your first option but it doesn't work. Whether the record exists or not, ret is returning NULL and nothing gets inserted.

When I switch the if statement to IF ret IS NULL, at least the new state gets inserted but both conditions return ret value of zero.

This is so perplexing, I see nothing wrong with the code! I absolutely need to have the new or existing id value returned in ret.

Comment: To troubleshoot I have further changed the 2nd "SELECT id into ret..." to "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO ret;". Now when the state is new, it returns the new id. The remaining problem is this: when it is an existing state, it is returning ret of zero.

Comment: The first return should be "RETURN ret;" Ret2 is not needed

Comment: I'm aware: this was done to troubleshoot since ret did not work. Do you see the line "insert into debug (dump1,dump2) values ('ret will be',ret);"? Well it's dumping zero in the debug table so right from the start there is a problem getting the ID from the first select statement. I've stared at that statement and see nothing wrong with it. I've run it directly in the MySQL console, replacing 'dname' with an actual value present in the state table and it correctly returns the id. So my thinking is something is wrong with the SELECT INTO but what exactly?

Comment: You need dump your insert value to make sure you are calling the function correctly.

Comment: I've dumped dname as well and it's perfectly fine. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77982/discussion-between-tim3880-and-user1729972).

Comment: The "...id INTEGER..." in the function definition parameter list was conflicting with the id used in the SELECT statement within the function body.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior with InnoDB. `insert` always increments the insert_id, even if the insert fails. The reason is that the database engine reserves the id before it tries to insert.

You can solve the problem by selecting first the row in the table, and insert the name only if it does not yet exist.

Also, you declare your function as deterministic, but it isn't. Just declaring it does not make it deterministic.

Comment: When I remove deterministic I get "Error Code: 1418
This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)". Putting NOT DETERMINISTIC also results in some other confusing mumbo jumbo.

Meanwhile, I think you address question 2 but what can I do about question 1?